# Using pipes to redirect a function-generated SQL query to the psql command

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pipe

I have a script that generates an SQL query as text e.g.

```
...
return "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM important_table"
```

which I would then like to run on a PostgreSQL database. I can do this in two lines like this:

```
python SQLgeneratingScript.py parameters > temp.sql 
psql -f temp.sql -d my_database
```

But seems like I should be able to one-line it with pipes, but I don't know how.

Comment: why are you not using a python database connector like psycopg2 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python SQLgeneratingScript.py parameters|psql -d my_database
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you are not using a python postgresql connector like [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/) ,but well if you want to do what you are trying to do using **Unix command redirection** you will have to do it like this in your code

```
...
print "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM important_table"  # or use sys.stdout.write()
```

this will write in your file `temp.sql` if you have ran your command like this:

```
python SQLgeneratingScript.py parameters > temp.sql
```

but well i will suggest writing in you file in python like this

```
def generate_sql():
   ...
   return "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM important_table"

with open('temp.sql', 'w') as f
   sql = generate_sql()
   f.write(sql)
```

or more use `psycopg2` to execute directly your sql

```
import psycopg2

def generate_sql():
    ...
    return "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM important_table"

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname= ...")

cur = conn.cursor()
sql = generate_sql()
cur.execute(sql)

conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks - datacenter will not let me install psycopg2 (and I'm still figuring out how to do ssh port forwarding) :(